# Loading list of snakemake inputs from file

Tags: python, snakemake

In Snakemake, is there a better way to write the following?
I have a file `inputs.txt` that contains paths to the real input files, and I would like this file to be regarded as one of the inputs of a rule.

```py
rule all:
    input: "test.txt"

def get_inputs(wildcards):
    fh = open("inputs.txt")
    return fh.read().splitlines()

rule test:
    input:
        "inputs.txt",  # unfortunately this won't trigger the exception
        additional=get_inputs
    output:
        "test.txt"
    shell:
        "echo {input.additional} > {output}"
```

My problem with this code is that when `inputs.txt` does not exist, it throws an exception on the `open()` call. I would prefer if it crashed before entering the `get_inputs` function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal is with this is to raise an explicit error if the file does not exist:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def get_inputs(wildcards):
    if Path("inputs.txt").exists():
        fh = open("inputs.txt")
        return fh.read().splitlines()
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("inputs.txt was not found or is a directory")
```